# Symfony log deprecated warning on new file

Tags: symfony, monolog

I want to log only the deprecated warnings to a new file. But I can't see how to achieve that with monolog. Is there a custom configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Deprecated Message are logged As INFO level, php Channels so if You try this configuration All deprecation message will be logged in one file

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        security:
            level:    INFO
            type:     stream
            path:     '%kernel.logs_dir%/deprecated.log'
            channels: [php]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I will try the same on production.

Comment: This will catch *all* messages in the `php` channel, not only the deprecations. For example, this will also include uncaught exceptions during the rendering of a twig template.